# How to check firestore rule for group membership

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to limit access to an entire app to a google group.

So my firestore rule could look like

```
   function isGoodEmail() {
      return request.auth != null && 
         request.auth.uid != null && 
         request.auth.token.email.matches('.*@example[.]com$') && 
         request.auth.token.email_verified;
   }

   function isAllowedUser() {
      return isGoodEmail() && request.auth.token.email in [
          "user1@example.com",
          "user2@example.com"
      ];
   }

   match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if isAllowedUser();
      }
   }
```

However, I don't really want to hardcode the list in the rules file, because it's also used elsewhere (e.g. on the homepage to show unauthorized user some special home page). I would like a condition like:

`request.auth.token.uid in "mygroup@example.com"`

Does firestore have any such provision or am I SOL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase security rules don't know anything at all about Google Groups.  All you have really access to is an email address.  If you don't want to hard code them, you could store them individually in documents and use a query to figure out if the email address exists.  But you would have to keep the database in sync with the group somehow.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured but it's pretty unsatisfactory to have a security system not understanding groups. Pretty much everywhere else in IAM/GCP you can work with groups. Having to distribute groups out over all documents in firestore is a non-starter for various reasons, including the one given by you.

Doug, thanks a ton getting back to me and confirming. It would be great if you could talk to the PM in charge and make him consider adding conditionals for group membership as a (very basic) feature request. I'm sure IAM has plenty of infrastructure already for this that can be used.

Comment: As I said, you can define your own groups and store them in Firestore documents.  You can check those documents in your rules.  They just won't be automatically synchronized with the Google Groups product, which is an entirely different thing from Firebase.  If you have feature requests, you can leave them with Firebase support. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support